# Why would I ssh to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ssh

I see that users including myself at work do ssh to 127.0.0.1. In my case I do it as a different user and to a non-standard port as part of reaching my Linux work environment (the hosting).

I wonder why I do that?

The command I use is `ssh username@127.0.0.1 -p xxxxx` where xxxxx is the port number (not port 22 but something completely different).

The procedure is part of me inheriting old Linux installations at work. What would be the difference between `ssh user@127.0.0.1` and just `su user` ?

Comment: Since we have absolutely no data about how the SSH service at xxxxx is set up, this question is essentially unanswerable. For all we know, there might be a container running with SSH forwarded from xxxxx, and the container environment might be entirely different.

Comment: The why could be anything, what the answers says or muru or something else. If we are able to answer it, we would need more information about the service running in the localhost:port, which most likely will take you to your sysadmin, which can tell you exactly why it is set up like that....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use `ssh user@127.0.0.1`, you are effectively logging in again, so you get the standard login environment for that user. `su user` will just change user.

A better comparison would be with `su - user`, which does set the environment. In that case, there seems to be little difference unless you are doing something special.

I wonder if the people who are using `ssh` are just using inherited company lore because no-one knew about `-` with `su`!

Comment: From an X session, could there be differences? I.E. does 'su - user' allow the resulting shell to use the current X session?

Comment: If you're in a command line window (e.g. `xterm`), yes it does.

Answer (score 4):

There wouldn't be a lot of difference unless they configured some special environment for the ssh connection.

You could look it up either in `/home/user/.ssh/ssh_config`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/sshd_config`.

Comment: Some environment variables would be different

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information in the question, there is no reason to assume that the SSH connection ends up on the local machine at all.

I've sometimes seen a particular port being forwarded from localhost to a ssh server on a remote host. Then `ssh user@localhost -p 12345` becomes equivalent to `ssh user@remote.example.com`, with the obvious differences from local `su`.

The reason for such a setup is usually that this way the users do not have to remember or know about `remote.example.com`, and can in fact be firewalled so that they cannot even access it directly. This also allows the admins to transparently change how the actual connection is routed.